# Finding the Last 10 Elements in a Array

Tags: java, arrays, list

Hey guys so I have to find the last 10 elements in my array in my `.txt` file filled with unsorted primes. The problem I'm having is the code I'm using to get the last 10 elements is just returning the same number instead of the last ten digits. If anyone can help me figure it out that would be great.

Also i have looked through some other code to figure it out, but i had no luck. If you do answer please don't just answer with a link to someone else code. Thanks

Heres my code so far:

```
public class BubbleSort {

static long BubbleSortCount = 0;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    System.out.print("This program compares the bubble, selection, merge sorts.\n"
            + "The data set is 78498 unsorted integers (prime numbers less than 1,000,000)\n\n");

    File file = new File("primes1.txt");

    Scanner infile = new Scanner(file);

    ArrayList<Integer> Primes1 = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    int temp;

    long startTime, endTime;

    int n;

    while (infile.hasNextInt()) {

        n = infile.nextInt();

        Primes1.add(n);

    }

    // bubble
    System.out.print("BUBBLE SORT\n");

    System.out.println("\nPrimes Read : " + Primes1.size());

    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    Primes1 = Bubble(Primes1);

    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    System.out.println("Elapsed Seconds = "

            + (double) ((endTime - startTime) / 1000.0));

    System.out.println("iterations = " + BubbleSortCount++);

    System.out.print("First 10 sorted : ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        System.out.print(Primes1.get(i) + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.print("Last 10 sorted : ");

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

        System.out.print(Primes1.get(Primes1.size() - 1) + " ");
    }

}

// Bubble sort Method

public static ArrayList<Integer> Bubble(ArrayList<Integer> Primes1) {

    int temp;

    for (int i = 0; i < Primes1.size() - 1; i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < Primes1.size() - 1; j++) {
            BubbleSortCount++;

            if (Primes1.get(j) > Primes1.get(j + 1)) {

                temp = Primes1.get(j);

                Primes1.set(j, Primes1.get(j + 1));

                Primes1.set(j + 1, temp);

            }

        }

    }

    return Primes1;

}
}
```

Here are the numbers in my .txt file.

> 7
>   2
>   47
>   13
>   11
>   59
>   17
>   41
>   37
>   23
>   29
>   31
>   19
>   53
>   43
>   241
>   251 
>   257 
>   263 
>   269 
>   271 
>   277 
>   281 
>   283
>   293

Comment: Out put is supposed to look like this

Comment: BUBBLE SORT

Primes Read : 25
Elapsed Seconds = 0.001
iterations = 576
First 10 sorted : 2 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 
Last 10 sorted :241 251 257 263 269 271 277 281 283 293

Comment: Please don't try to add details about your question as comments on it, SO is not a discussion board.  Instead [edit] your question to add information to it.

Comment: On a side note; an `ArrayList` is not the same thing as an `Array` so the  title of the question is slightly misleading.

Answer (score 1):

```
    System.out.print(Primes1.get(Primes1.size() - 1) + " ");
```

With the 1 it will always take the same number, should be fixed

```
    System.out.print(Primes1.get(Primes1.size() - i) + " ");
```

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you get the same number is that you never use the index in the for-loop to get the 10 last.

This:

```
System.out.print("Last 10 sorted : ");    
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {    
  System.out.print(Primes1.get(Primes1.size() - 1) + " ");
}
```

must be changed to use the loop index variable. This should do it:

```
System.out.print("Last 10 sorted : ");
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  System.out.print(Primes1.get(Primes1.size() - 10 + i) + " ");
}
```

Another way would be to use the [sublist](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#subList-int-int-) method from the *List* interface to produce a new list with the 10 last elements, like this:

```
List<Integer> last10list = Primes1.subList(Primes1.size() - 11, Primes1.size());
```

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    System.out.print(Primes1.get(Primes1.size() - 1) + " ");
}
```

To:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    System.out.print(Primes1.get(Primes1.size() - (i+1)) + " ");
}
```

Or:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {

    System.out.print(Primes1.get(Primes1.size() - i) + " ");
}
```

Explanation:

In the original code, the loop iterates from 0 to 9, and for each iteration, it prints the last element of the list `Primes1`. The modified versions provide two alternatives:

Option 1: Iterating backward using (`i+1`) as an offset. This means the loop starts from `0` but retrieves elements from the end of the list with an increasing offset, effectively reversing the order.

Option 2: Iterating backward starting from `1`. In this case, the loop starts from `1` and iterates up to `10`, printing elements from the end of the list with a decreasing index.

These changes can be useful in scenarios where you need to reverse the order of elements or access elements in a different sequence. Choose the option that best fits your specific requirements.

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.